# Typescript generic parameters that extends exclusive unions

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, pattern-matching, union

In TypeScript, is there a way to define a generic parameter that extends only one value of a union type?

For example, assuming I declare a union type as follows:

```
type Any = "A" | "B"
```

then if I use the type in a function definition as follows:

```
const fn = <T extends Any>(arg: T[]) => {}
```

then the *args* argument can be an array that contain the values of both "A" and "B"; for example, this would be valid:

```
let x = fn(["A", "B"])
```

which defeats the very purpose of using the generic parameter in the function definition (i.e., to constrain the values in *args* argument array to only one specific type)

Of course, I could define the function as follows:

```
const fn = (arg: "A"[] | "B"[]) => {}
```

But if the number of component types in the union is large, this may be impractical

Comment: So you want to forbid `fn(null as ("A" | "B")[])` ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir No I want to forbid `let x = fn(["A", "B"])`

Comment: Yes .. that is the same thing as far as the inferred `T` is concerned :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir: Yes, actually it is the same thing, my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a proposed feature that would allow you to tell the compiler that `T` is one of a number of types instead of a union of them. The [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) is marked as in discussion, so maybe add a +1 for it.

In the meantime we can force the compiler to give us an error if `T` is a union using conditional types:

```
type Any = "A" | "B"

type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never
type NoUnion<T, TError> = [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>] ? {} : TError

type d = NoUnion<Any, ""> 
const fn = <T extends Any>(arg: T[] & NoUnion<T, "Must be A or B not a union">) => { }

fn(null as "A"[])
fn(null as "B"[])
fn(null as ("A" | "B")[]) //error Type 'Any[]' is not assignable to type '"Must be A or B not a union"'
```

Comment: Ok @Titian, but the type error does not give a proper message when you pass an actual argument to fn (e.g., `fn(["A", "B"])`). The error I get is: _Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Any'_. In any case, your solution can simply be reduced to `const fn = <T extends Any>(arg: T extends (infer X)? X[] : never) => { }`

Comment: @prmph Yeah that is also a good option :) But you will notice that `T` is no lobger the actual type its always `"A" | B"`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution and it is very straightforward.  I've spiced it up by adding a return type also - get that over with.

```
type Any = "A" | "B" | "C" | "D" | "E"
type Fn<T> = (arg:T[])=>T

// This distributive conditional operator maps the 
// union of elements-of-Any to a union-of-functions with exclusive Parameters 
type FnAny_<T> = T extends any ? Fn<T> : never;
type FnAny = FnAny_<Any>

// Obviously you have to define the real content of `fnAny` 
// to correctly match the definition - this is a dummy defn
function fnAny<T extends FnAny>(...a:Parameters<T>):ReturnType<T>{
  if (Math.random()<0.5)
    return undefined as unknown as ReturnType<T>
  else 
    return undefined as unknown as ReturnType<T>
}
fnAny(["A","A"]) // ok
fnAny(["A","E"]) // ERROR - rejected by type checker
```

This solution works on the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiKBeKAiGqoB80CFM6oDCBaAIqagKKoCwAUKJFAGJwA8AKgHzJQAUAQwBOAcwBcnANoBdAJRJunBk2ht4IAPpdeKTlAgAPYBDgATAM5RBCKAH5WHHlHFQ4EAG4RhAbhXg1OA0+dQRtDW4GADMAVzgAY2AASwB7OCgooIQuA2NTS0cI-gA6UsFxAAURQQBbCBNhCx05cQAlepjhOE4AnQBvBigoJKiBAFlBYAALYuEbMxSa-jl2AAZigFY5QaGoYQ6uqDizCCik9zNrKziAazgUgHd0wSt24E7u3p4diAAbC2gOyG+3eh2Op3OEEuLyOcDuj2erwOn0gOgYAF9olkQPwpOhUAAafHyKAAelJUBSNyxGlx+KJNBJ5Kgqig8SmEHiNygVFarQA8q0oAxmbsYGIYnU4MBKaNWQByKT8fHYNA0OSyGTy4ZWe4yl4WJKiOCCABGv2gwBSUDA1TqDVlLICUEVIgkaAwmtVUjdrlQ+C9OB9Yj9JEDUGD7tQFHDkb9NE18uKIopuyGPWYiuVGFV1FQGpkWp1bhS+oshuNZotLOtCrjatQieT9FFafTzvl2co6tk2qSutLVwrJvNltrHbzvebrbb7czKsIND7A7Lw6rY6d86X09Ts7TGeg8vxy5Lq6NI+rVs3h7zSZTaflghPJ3ivxEUKgppiMqSwCsHkEX4Ymgfs3E8bw9ggQQzGbBgGCAA) for all available versions
from 3.3.3333 to the latest 4.5.4.

The error message:

- Argument of type '[("A" | "E")[]]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[arg: "A"[]] | [arg: "B"[]] | [arg: "C"[]] | [arg: "D"[]] | [arg: "E"[]]'.
- Type '[("A" | "E")[]]' is not assignable to type '[arg: "E"[]]'.
- Type '("A" | "E")[]' is not assignable to type '"E"[]'.
- Type '"A" | "E"' is not assignable to type '"E"'.
- Type '"A"' is not assignable to type '"E"'.